# Dynamically change the color of a cell in django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, html-table, django-tables2

I want to change dynamically the background color of a cell based in the value.
I render my table using django-tables2 and works fine. 
This is my code to render the table in the template:

```
{% load querystring from django_tables2 %}
{% load trans blocktrans from i18n %}
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}

{% if table.page %}
    <div class="table-container">
{% endif %}

{% block table %}
    <table class="table table-compact table-bordered"{% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
        {% block table.thead %}
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for column in table.columns %}
                    {% if column.orderable %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}">{{ column.header }}</a></th>
                    {% else %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>{{ column.header }}</th>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endblock table.thead %}
        {% block table.tbody %}
            <tbody>
            {% for row in table.page.object_list|default:table.rows %} {# support pagination #}
                {% block table.tbody.row %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle "odd" "even" %}">
                        {% for column, cell in row.items %}
                            <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{{ cell }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endblock table.tbody.row %}
            {% empty %}
                {% if table.empty_text %}
                    {% block table.tbody.empty_text %}
                        <tr><td colspan="{{ table.columns|length }}">{{ table.empty_text }}</td></tr>
                    {% endblock table.tbody.empty_text %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        {% endblock table.tbody %}
        {% block table.tfoot %}
            <tfoot></tfoot>
        {% endblock table.tfoot %}
    </table>
{% endblock table %}
   </div>
{% if table.page %}
    {% block pagination %}
        {{ table.page|pagination }}
    {% endblock pagination %}
{% endif %}
```

My doubt if django-tables2 or Django have some properties to evaluate the value of a cell or I need to create a JavaScript function.
Please can bring me some link or snippet to implement this functionality

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the value you are looking for going to change often or are the values you looking for to make different going to be the same? Would {% if %} work?

Comment: The values change constantly and I try to use the {% if %} but I receive an error: Could not parse the remainder '% If cell.e_reception == 2 %'. I will search for this error. If I find something I let you know. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

This answer was a long time coming, but you're now able to do this with `attrs` on your column, as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/Asday/django-tables2-kwattrs-test/blob/master/website/columns.py).

```
class StatusColumn(Column):
    attrs = {'td': {'class': lambda value: f'status-{value}'}}
```

This will set the `class` HTML attribute on the `<td />` element to match the cell's value.

Also, it looks like you're manually doing a lot of the work that `{% render_table ... %}` does nowadays, so if you revisit this, do take a look at what you can simplify with the newer features.